# Mac OS X Lion - mysql: command not found

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

I have installed MySQL from [this source](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), installation was successfully finished.
But when I run in terminal **which mysql**, the output is empty.
When **mysql**, the output is

> -bash: mysql: command not found

Also, I updated bundle and ran the app - the result:

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.28 but the client library is 5.6.12. (RuntimeError)
```

Can I ask you for help how to tackle this issue?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
I also tried to install the gem to the mysql directory, like

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.28/bin/mysql_config
```

But unfortunately the same - successfully installed, but when I run the app, still the same error

Comment: my guess is that you need up update you PATH variable:  http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/

Comment: I just tried this, but it unfortunately didn't helped me.

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.28/bin/mysql_config`?

Comment: The usage output with options.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've had problems installing the mysql2 gem, so I wrote a little shell script to make my life easier:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Try updating that with the path to your mysql_config:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.28/bin/mysql_config
```

and change `mysql` to `mysql2`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer man, I've tried to run the command in terminal, but still the same error, nothing has changed.