# Trying to connect to mysql server for the first time and get an error messange: "mysql: command not found"

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am setting up my first data base using XAMPP. I followed the steps from 
dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html
but as I try to connect to mysqlserver by typing "mysql -u root" into my Terminal I get back an error message:

```
Phosphoros:~ Arthur$ mysql -u root

-bash: mysql: command not found

Phosphoros:~ Arthur$
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5.

How can I connect to the server?

Arthur

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949903/mac-os-x-lion-mysql-command-not-found

Comment: did you install the mysql client?

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal application doesn't know where to locate the mysql program.

For example, if you installed xampp in C:/xampp, you open a command prompt, cd to C:/xampp/mysql/bin and then run your command, which should work now.

Edit: Just remembered you mentioned OSX, regardless, use the same principle. In your terminal, cd to the XAMPP install subfolder which contains the mysql executable app

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the command: `mysql -u root` in the mysql directory that exists in the `/opt/lampp` directory.